# I Made My Model Backwards Anyway To Fix?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bones

So realizing after some time I didn't know it was facing the wrong or made it on the opposite side

Also a way to fix it without deforming it

[image]

I'm hoping I can fix it, if not I have to make a new model.

Comment: Maybe try pressing CTRL+M and then Y (will mirror-flip the object on the y axis)

Comment: Tried It Almost Worked But The Feet Are Deformed